# Second-order differential equation with constant complex coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

So I've come across this differential equation which I'm supposed to solve using 2 boundary conditions

\begin{equation}
 \nu \frac{\partial^{2} w}{\partial z^{2}}-i f w=g \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\nu\left(\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\right)_{z=0}=\tau^{w} \\
w_{z=-h}=0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Ignoring for now the boundary conditions, the general solution is presented like:
\begin{equation}
w=C_{1} e^{\sqrt{\frac{i f}{\nu}} \cdot z}+C_{2} e^{-\sqrt{\frac{i f}{\nu}} \cdot z}+\frac{i g}{f} \frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial n}
\end{equation}

Calculating the roots of the characteristic equation:

\begin{equation}
 m_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{\sqrt{-4 \nu \left ( -if \right )}}{2\nu}=\sqrt{\frac{if}{\nu}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 m_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-\sqrt{-4 \nu \left ( -if \right )}}{2\nu}=-\sqrt{\frac{if}{\nu}}
\end{equation}

These are complex conjugated roots, not real (and different) ones. At this point, I would write something according to this kind of solution

\begin{equation}
\left(m_{1,2}=\alpha+i \beta\right) \quad y=e^{\alpha x}\left(C_{1} \cos \beta x+C_{2} \operatorname{sen} \beta x\right)
\end{equation}

Not according to this:

\begin{equation}
\left(m_{1} \neq m_{2}\right) \quad y=C_{1} e^{m_{1} x}+C_{2} e^{m_{2} x}
\end{equation}

Can someone help me see how can the solutions be equivalent?

Comment: It just comes down to the fact that $e^{a\pm bi} = e^a\cos b \pm ie^a\sin b$. So you can combine these with arbitrary coefficients to get the forms you need

Comment: @MPW : That only works for purely real DE, here you have exponent factors $\pm(1+i)a$, an opposite pair, not a conjugate pair.

Comment: @LutzLehmann : $\sin z, \cos z, \sinh z, \cosh z, e^z, e^{-z}$, etc -- all the same, in the sense that they are just linear combinations of exponential functions. You can write any of them as combinations of any of the others

Comment: @MPW : Yes, but your particular decomposition and combination claim only applies to the real situation. Of course you can write $Ae^{mx}+Be^{-mx}=C\cosh(mx)+D\sinh(mx)$ even when $m=m_1$ is a complex number.

Comment: @LutzLehmann : Yes, and you can also write the real-valued solution in the form $e^{\alpha x}(C_1\cos \beta x + C_2\sin \beta x)$ for an appropriate choice of the constants, some of which may be complex. That's all I was saying.

Comment: @MPW : No, that will be quite impossible except in a very trivial way, with $α=0$, as $α=\frac12(m_1+m_2)=0$.